# how to log just the output of commands with expect

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I'm using expect to execute a bunch of commands in a remote machine. Then, i'm calling the expect script from a shell script.

I don't want the expect script to log to stdout the sent commands but i want it to log the output of the commands, so my shell script can do other things depending on that results.

```
log_user 0
```

Hides both the commands and the results, so it doesn't fit my needs. How can i tell expect to log the results?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I'm not sure you can do that, since the reason for seeing the commands you send is because the remote device echoes them back to you. This is standard procedure, and is done so that a user sees what he or she types when interacting with the device.

What I'm trying to say is that both the device output to issued commands, **and** the echoed-back commands, are part of the spawned process's stdout, therefore I don't believe you can separate one from the other.

Now that I think of it, I think you can configure a terminal to **not** display echoed commands... but not sure how you would go about doing that with a spawned process that is not using an interactive terminal.

Let us know if you find a way, I'd be interested of knowing if there is one.

Comment: The only way i found by the moment is to set log_user to 0, capture output of each command using expect_out and print them with puts, but that is overkill and error-prone.

Comment: Can't you adapt your shell script to expect the commands in the output, and deal with / ignore them? Would that not be the easier route?

Comment: I didn't feel comfortable with the expect solution so I end up using python's [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) since it allows executing commands and getting stdout, stderr and exit status and allows connecting to ssh with password or with ssh keys